# How to make my table resposive when I click `+` button from first column, then display Pthers columns in my Datatable

Tags: javascript, json, datatables

This is the code from my div

```
<div id="TableDomain1"></div>
```

How to make it responsible table like Datatable Responsive

```
function Domain(did2) {          
    $.ajax({url: url,async: false, success: function success(data) {
        data = JSON.parse(data);                               
        var table = '<table id="TableDomain" class="display responsive nowrap collapsed;width:100%;" cellspacing="0"><thead><tr><th style="font-size: 12px">Id</th><th style="font-size: 12px">Name</th></tr></thead><tbody>';

        var row = "";
        $.each(data, function (index, value) {
        row = '<tr><td>' + value.Id + '</td><td>' + value.Name + '</td></tr>';
        table += row;
    });

    table += '</tbody></table>';
    $("#TableDomain1").html(table);
}
```

Comment: My Responsive Table Not Working

Comment: **`$("#TableDomain").DataTable({ "responsive": true })` ????**